Another riddle I have for you. Will you try to solve it, and see it through
In the shadows where the raven's cry is heard,
A leader's fate in ancient words inferred.
Betrayed by friends, his reign no more,
His name echoes with nevermore.
- Nolan E. Nygma

Does this riddle use clues following the rules of British-style [[tag:cryptic-crosswords]]? On this site, the [[tag:cryptic-clues]] tag means a very specific style of wordplay clue, not just any clue stated cryptically. (Nor, for that matter, is [[tag:enigmatic-puzzle]], which is for when the genre/type of puzzle is unknown. If this is a riddle, and just a riddle - no secret sudokus or crosswords, but just wordplay and the like - then it's not our definition of [enigmatic-puzzle])

In your previously (currently unsolved) puzzle the last line of the verse suggests you want "the name of this wise man." But here, it is less clear what the solution will be, and one answer says it refers to XXX but that person isn't a leader as implied by the second line and 'his name'. It's a bit opaque.

Bobble, yes the tags are correct.

Weather, can you rephrase that for me?

I believe this riddle might be referring to

 author Edgar Allan Poe.

Going line-by-line:
In the shadows where the raven's cry is heard,

 One of Poe's most famous works is the poem The Raven; the poem contains multiple references to shadows in its final stanza.

A leader's fate in ancient words inferred.

 The Masque of the Red Death is one of Poe's short stories in which a prince (leader) hides from a plague that ends up killing him after all; one of the most common literary interpretations is the inevitability of death and fate. I believe "ancient words" could refer to the term "masque" that has fallen out of favor in modern times.

Betrayed by friends, his reign no more,

 The Cask of Amontillado is a Poe short story about a betrayal by a close friend. Fortunato, the victim of this betrayal, is a nobleman.

His name echoes with nevermore.

 "Quoth the raven 'Nevermore'" is an iconic quote from The Raven and is also probably the single most well-known line of Poe's.


But is it a solution to the riddle? "A leader ... his reign ... His name".
